# Cache-Control header to bust device cache but allow CDN

Tags: rest, http, mobile, frontend, cdn

I am implementing an HTTP polling mechanism to detect device network status. I am planning to make a periodic GET request to a static file `/static/byte.txt` to validate the device's internet access.

I am using the `Cache-Control: no-cache` request header to make sure I am not served with a cached copy of the file on the device (which defeats the purpose). But I would like to still use any cached copy of the file on the CDN, as there is no need to download the file from the origin (my servers) every time. Does anyone know of a way to set the cache control headers to achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cache-Control **request** header is a poor fit for this use case as both the client HTTP library and the CDN will assign the same meaning to whatever cache control directive you choose.

Instead, I recommend using a Cache-Control **response** header. In the response, you can use something like `Cache-Control: max-age=0, s-maxage=604800`, which indicates that the client should not cache the response but the CDN can cache it for up to a week (604,800 seconds).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I just found the CloudFront docs that explains how it interprets both values and you are correct.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html